# Switch statement not triggering

Tags: javascript, discord.io

I'm unsure why my uncommented switch will not trigger.

What should happen, is user inputs D[int], for example, D20.
And the script splits D and the string apart. Converts the string into an actual int labelled X. then if that int is above 0, it provides a random number between 0 and X.

However, the case statement is not firing when (X < 0):

I'm super new to all of this so any help is truly appreciated!

The code is attached below.

```html
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
   
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == 'D') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        var X = Number(cmd)
        
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case (X > 0):
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,X)
                });
            break;
/*            case '4':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,4)
                });
            break;
            case '6':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,6)
                });
            break;
            case '8':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,8)
                });
            break;
            case '10':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,10)
                });
            break;
            case '12':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,12)
                });
            break;
            case '20':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,20)
                });
            break;
            case '100':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: getRndInteger(1,100)
                });
            break; 
            */
          // Just add any case commands if you want to..
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: THere is no ```case``` for ```x<0```;

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to just use `getRndInteger(1, cmd)` instead of the switch statement?

Comment: use `default:` to define what the switch case should do with values that don't have specific cases.

Comment: `case x < 0` will be either `case true` or `case false` depending on the value of `x` and `cmd` is neither of those

Comment: `case (X > 0)` is basically saying  `(X > 0) === X` Do "true === X" is never going to happen.